# Can I use a string to call a variable in R

Tags: r

I have a list of unique `Test`, which I have identified using

```
unique_test <- unique(Historic_data$Test ID`)
```

I am using the loop below to create a variable of each unique test ID with the hours observed for each:

```
for (i in 1:length(unique_test)) {
  assign(paste0(unique_test[i]), Historic_data[Historic_data$`Test ID` == (unique_test[i]), c("hours")])
}
```

I am then trying to continue the for loop and use something like `unique_JP[i][, "hours", drop = TRUE]` to access the hours within each variable, but it flags errors.

Please can someone advise on my mistake?

Comment: First error is the wrong place to ask. This is a programming question, not a statistics question. Second error is to not come up with a minimal reproducible example. Third: often when questions come up with `assign` in a loop it would be far better to store the data in a list rather then in named variables. Please ask that with a mvre on stackoverflow or at another suitable place.

Comment: As @Bernhard said, this belongs at stackoverflow. I suggest it be migrated.